# Deployment animation with hover and after combined in CSS

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a button created with HTML and CSS that displays text when hovering over it. What I want to achieve is that there is an transition animation, since I have not been able to do it.

In the HTML code the button is worked with the link **a tag**.

Hope they can recreate the codes. I leave a link to a website so that you can check it in its entirety: https://policies.esims.one/terms (the button is the first to appear on the page.)

```css
.back-button{
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: normal;
line-height: 100%;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
border-radius: 0px;box-shadow: none;padding: 5px 30px 5px 5px;
color: #181818;
font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
}
.back-button::before{
margin-right:10px;
background-image:url(https://mcusercontent.com/ec104f3d77537e1962ab6441c/images/d7bb4928-a156-4682-9677-d0d5b47c3a21.png);
background-size:40px 40px;
display:inline-block;
width:40px;
height:40px;
border-radius:50%;
content:""
}
.back-button:hover:after{
content:"Home"
}
.mcnButton{
transition:.4s;
border-radius:50px!important;
box-shadow:#999 0 0 20px 0!important;outline:none;
user-select:none
}
.mcnButton:focus{
background:#eceff9!important;
color:#181818!important
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;">
<a class="back-button mcnButton" href="https://www.example.com/" target="_self">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: button inside link is an invalid code

Answer (score 1):

**Hello there**, I tried to use your `code` it will work perfectly if you will use your code:

```
<a class="back-button mcnButton" href="https://www.example.com/" target="_self"></a>
```

covert to:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/" target="_self">
<button class="back-button mcnButton"><button></a>
```

also no change in the CSS.